# "Update" is unknown import symbol

Tags: python, bots, telegram, replit

I wrote Python code for a basic Telegram bot through replit.

In the shell I wrote: `pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7`

Until now it was working for me, but from now on, it writes me things like: "Update" is unknown import symbol, "Filters" is unknown import symbol, and the main error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/PeachpuffSquareTraining/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram import Update
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram' (/home/runner/PeachpuffSquareTraining/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/__init__.py)
```

This is the code I tried, and until now with the above pip it was working for me:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the actual token you obtained from BotFather
TOKEN = 'the token is secret'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your bot.')

def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Command handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Message handler for echoing messages
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you send a signal to stop it
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you check [this link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-am-i-getting-importerror-cannot-import-name-xy-from-telegram)?

Did you installed the `pip install telegram` before?

Comment: Why is the line #1 from your traceback different than the one from your code?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from telegram import Update

# Replace 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN' with the actual token you obtained from BotFather
TOKEN = 'the token is secret'

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! I am your bot.')

def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text(update.message.text)

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # Command handlers
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    # Message handler for echoing messages
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you send a signal to stop it
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You should import Update from the `telegram` lib:
[image: Telegram 13.7 document]